# NSProgressIndicator not moving

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, swift2, nsprogressindicator

Recently I wrote a small program that encrypts and decrypts some text in a certain way. However, this process can be quite lengthy, so I decided to add a progress bar at the bottom of the view to gauge how long left. (I am using storyboards for Mac OSX on Swift 2.0)

To make the bar move I added:

```
self.ProgressBar.doubleValue = 100 * (progress / Double(self.Text1.stringValue.characters.count))
```

In a loop in which `progress` keeps on increasing.

However, the progress bar is stuck at 0% and only updates when the program has finished immediately going to 100%

Any way to fix this?

PS: This is using a loop that is running in the main thread, and I think that's the problem, but I can't seem to fix it myself. I have already tried using `ProgressBar.displayIfNeeded()` and

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.ProgressBar.doubleValue = 100 * (progress / Double(self.Text1.stringValue.characters.count))  }
```

but to no avail, although it's possible that I used them incorrectly, as I am quite new to programming.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the encryption process in the main UI thread? If so, it will block the UI until it's down - you will need to run it in another thread which updates the UI thread with progress.

Comment: Just note: if you have some modal window/ sheet window then the execution runs in different run loop and your code is not called. Can you debug this if methods/functions are called?